# Comparing an object created with in-game gameobjects with some predefined model unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm making a game, where the player with some planes (of different forms) constructs 3d shapes, they get join by joints. But the idea is that I need to check if the figure they have made is the one asked for.
Does someone know how to check this? 
Please help, i'm new with unity.

**Edit**

The idea is that at the start of the game I will show them for example a cube, and with the planes they need to create the same figure (in this case the cube) and when they finish (there will be a finish button or something) i need to review if the figure they have made is in this case the cube, but it can be other figures like pyramids, prisms, etc.

Comment: _check if the figure they have made is the one asked for._ define asked for.

Comment: I have edited the question, i hope i made myself clear, i'm not so good with english.

Comment: If I was given this task by someone else, I would back away slowly, change my name, and move to Canada.  There are a lot of areas where the positioning of each quad could be in multiple orientations (uh...8 per face) and still "look" correct.  And that's *ignoring scale.*  Your program would have to identify the center of the figure, calculate relative offsets to each face, verify against expected, then check each face against 8 possible isomorphic rotations. This is going to be a headache no matter what you do.

Comment: I totally agree with Draco, that was the approach I thought of, but i think it would be rather difficult to implement.